# git pushing new branch error : 'set the remote as upstream'

Tags: git

This is what my current git branches looks like

```
C:\Users\workspace\my-sme-services>git branch
develop_MVP
* features/FEAT-1245
master
```

`features/FEAT-1245` is derived from `develop_MVP`.  I have done committing my code into my branch , `features/FEAT-1245`  Now when i try push my branch , i get the following errors.

```
C:\Users\workspace\my-rhb-sme-services>git push
fatal: The current branch features/FEAT-1245 has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

git push --set-upstream origin features/FEAT-1245
```

how do i proceed to push this branch across?

Comment: Git is showing you hint, just use it, Copy the line  and run it.. git push --set-upstream origin features/FEAT-1245

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+fatal%3A+The+current+branch+has+no+upstream+branch

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As the message say, you should use the command:

```
git push --set-upstream origin features/FEAT-1245
```

Or you can use a shortcut:

```
git push -u origin features/FEAT-1245
```

Comment: how about git asked for password after i try to ```git push --set-upstream origin features/my-branch``` ? but after that permission denied